# Reorder tr's of a table depening on an order array using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I need your help with something I am working.I have created a `HTML` table which has 7 categories (7 `tr`'s). Each `tr` has 2 `td`'s, one is the name of category and the other is an input checkbox. So if user selects for example 1, 3, 7 (1st checkbox for the 1st category, 3rd checkbox for the 3rd category etc) a `javascript` array will be created like `order = [1, 3, 7];`.

So I want (on page reload) to move these selected `tr`'s on the top of the table using a `jQuery` script.

HTML table:

```
<tbody id="news_body">
<tr id="1">
<td class="categories">World</td>
<td class="category_enabled" style="float: right;"><input type="checkbox" value="1"/></td>
</tr>

<tr id="2">
<td class="categories">Sports</td>
<td class="category_enabled" style="float: right;"><input type="checkbox" value="2"/></td>       
 </tr>
.
.
.
<tr id="7">
<td class="categories">Economy</td>
<td class="category_enabled" style="float: right;"><input type="checkbox" value="7"/></td>      
</tr>
</tbody>
```

I have already tried this but `tr`'s are displayed to the bottom of the table:

```
var order = [1, 3, 7];
$.each(order, function(){
     $("#news_body").append($("#" + this));
})
```

Any ideas will be helpful..

SOLUTION FOUND (UPDATED):

```
$.each(categories, function(){
   $("#news_table").append($("#" + this));
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this moderation

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var order = [1, 3, 7];
reverse_order=order.reverse();// reversing array so when prepending, checkboxes will display in right order
$.each(reverse_order, function(key,value){

    var selected=$("#" + value);// keep the original tr
    $("#" + value).remove();// remove from table 
     $("#news_body").prepend(selected);// then prepend it 
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

What you want to use is [prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/).
This will insert the elem to the beginning of the table.

```
var order = [1, 3, 7];
$.each(order, function(index, value){
    $("#news_body").prepend($("#" + this));
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your time.I believe I found the solution!